# Knative Eventing - NewObservedGenFailure error for helloworld sample's trigger

Tags: knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

I am trying out sample hello world application to make use of knative events. Using the reference guide: https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/helloworld/helloworld-python/

I manage to create service, deployment & trigger using the sample-app.yaml.
However when I run

`kubectl --namespace knative-samples get trigger helloworld-python`
to check on the trigger status, I got this error "NewObservedGenFailure".

`knative-samples   helloworld-python   default                    21m   Unknown   NewObservedGenFailure`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7E91.png)

Any insight on what is causing this? Or how can I troubleshoot this issue? Could not get much info from google. Thank you

Comment: Its likely that that there is a configuration issue for the trigger. What do you get when running `kubectl --namespace knative-samples describe trigger helloworld-python`?  That should provide additional info to help debug.

Comment: Hi thanks! I have resolved my issue. The guide did not state about broker creation. Once I created the broker. The trigger works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just blindly following the guide which did not state about broker creation. The trigger issue is resolved after  creating the broker.